# Scene loaded from existing controller not align with center - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm writing a program which consists of two different scenes, each one is designed with an FXML file and each of them has its own controller. My initial scene works fine, and it appears in the center of the screen, but when I try to load the second scene from the controller of the first one, I get that it doesn't appears in the center of the screen like the other one does.

Can anyone please help me? It is freaking me out!
Here's some code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        //Create an FXMLLoader
        FXMLLoader rootLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainScene.fxml"));

        //Instantiate a new controller with parameter and sets it to the FXMLLoader
        MainController mainController = new MainController(primaryStage);
        rootLoader.setController(mainController);

        //Sets the layout
        Group root = rootLoader.load();
        Scene startScene = new Scene(root);

        //Sets the stage's scene
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(startScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is from the Main.

```
public void initialize() {

    FXMLLoader playSceneLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("PlayScene.fxml"));

    try {
        Group playSceneLayout = playSceneLoader.load();
        playScene = new Scene(playSceneLayout, Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxX(), Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxY());
        playScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is from the first controller which create the initial scene of the program.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<Group xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GridPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="500.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #A47888#A47888;">
               <children>
                  <Label fx:id="playLabel" layoutX="90.0" layoutY="129.0" onMouseClicked="#startLabelClicked" text="Play" textFill="#77354c">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="AvidOmnes Light" size="41.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #77354C#77354C;" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <children>
                  <Label fx:id="titleLabel" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="129.0" text="Titolo" textFill="#a47888">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="AvidOmnes Light" size="40.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="closeLabel" layoutX="232.0" layoutY="6.0" onMouseClicked="#closeRoot" text="X" textFill="#a47888" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</Group>
```

This is the FXML file of the initial page.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>


<Group xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.PlayController">
   <children>
      <Circle fx:id="startCircle" fill="DODGERBLUE" onMouseClicked="#startCircleClicked" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
   </children>
</Group>
```

And this is the second scene's one.

Comment: Did you display your scenes in the same stage or in a different one ? What is not centered in your screen, the second `Scene` in the same `Stage` or the second `Stage` ?

Comment: I guess the Scene, because the first controller doesn't create any new Stage.

Comment: Ok, maybe I get it, you expect your `Circle` to be in the middle of your screen as soon as you click on your `label` "Play" ?

Comment: No, my Circle is inside the Group, so I expect to see it in the top left corner of the Group, and I actually see just a slice of it, but this does not happen in the top left corner of the screen. I get a slice of the Circle in some point close to the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's absolutely normal that you get only a slice of your `Circle` as you do not define center coordinate and then is by default located in the position (0, 0) of the `Group`.

In order to see it in top-left corner of your screen, you have to maximize your `Stage` as soon as you click on your `Label`.

Here is an example:  (as you were stingy of information about your code I improvise, so the important modification is in the `startLabelClicked`)

```
public class MainController {

    private Stage mainStage;
    private Scene playScene;

    public MainController(Stage pMainStage) {
        mainStage = pMainStage;
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        FXMLLoader playSceneLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("PlayScene.fxml"));

        try {
            Parent playSceneLayout = playSceneLoader.load();
            playScene = new Scene(playSceneLayout, Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxX(), Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxY());
            playScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void startLabelClicked() {
        mainStage.setScene(playScene);
        // This line will help you to extend your stage, which contains your scene.
        mainStage.setMaximized(true);
    }

    @FXML
    private void closeRoot() {
        System.out.println("Closing.");
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for have looked stingy, but I didn't want to post tons of code, for legibility reasons. Anyway, now it works! But I still have some doubts. Why did you put the mainStage between parenthesis? And now another little issue: when the second scene loads, my Circle slides from its start position to the top left corner. How can I avoid this "animation"?

Comment: The parenthesis is a typo error (I used another component to get the stage before I saw you pass the stage as parameter), I will edit the post and remove them. I do not reproduce the 'slide' of the `Circle`. I will have a look (but I am using java 8, not java 10 like you, maybe that's the reason).

Comment: Moreover, when you post a problem to get a solution, the best way is to write a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Easier for every one, you because it helps you to reproduce the problem in another way, and the persons who can help you because it is more understandable and they can copy, test and modify the code easily.

Comment: @AndreaMilitano I did not succeed to reproduce the `Circle` "animation". Moreover from what I understand, I don't think you should change the `Scene`, you should change the `Root` of your `Scene` instead, that will avoid you to pass the mainStage as parameter of you second controller constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Without adjusting the `x` and `y` properties of the circle, the center of the circle is positioned at the top left of the scene. Since javafx does not display anything outside of the scene, you're left with the bottom right quater of a circle.

To display a circle completely in a scene with in the top left corner of a scene, you should put the circle in a layout that does some layout. E.g. `AnchorPane` with `topAnchor` and `leftAnchor` properties set for the circle would work, but the simplest way of accomplishing the desired result is to use a `StackPane` with a top left alignment:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>

<StackPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.PlayController">
   <children>
      <Circle fx:id="startCircle" fill="DODGERBLUE" onMouseClicked="#startCircleClicked" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
   </children>
</StackPane>
```